# Export Crystal Report to CSV Format

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, csv

How to export the crystal report to .csv file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a nice structured ResultSet, you can export your crystal reports to Excel format, and then do a simple export from Excel into CSV. There are plenty of code snippets out there on how to programmatically work with Excel spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the free version of Crystal reports that comes with .NET?

If so, apparently you can't. There is a post [here](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=1216) that states

> The free version of VS.NET doesn't have the CSV export options. You have to upgrade to get that capability.